# ¿Cómo saber si un elemento tiene asignado algún evento con Snap?

Tags: javascript, snap.svg

Sin tener que recurrir a jQuery y mediante el [Snap.SVG](http://snapsvg.io/), ¿cómo puedo listar o comparar si un elemento tiene algún evento asignado?

Por ejemplo si tengo añadido un controlador de eventos para el "elemento":

```
elemento.click(laFuncionClic);
```

¿Existe algún método o propiedad para extraer los eventos del elemento, y comparar después?

Comment: ¿Alguna razón del porqué no quieres recurrir a JQuery?, además, ayudaría a futuros usuarios que desean contribuir con respuestas, si colocas qué es `Snap`

Comment: Snap es una librería javaScript para gráficos vectoriales, desarrollada por Adobe: http://snapsvg.io/.
He creado una animación como presentación de una página web, utilizando únicamente esta librería, que por cierto, lleva incluida la libreria jQuery. Pero Snap tiene incluidos muchos métodos, cuya sintaxis es bastante más abreviada que la de jQuery (como el ejemplo), y por tanto más fácil de comprender. Creo que lo que yo busco, no existe en Snap, pero ya encontré una alternativa al problema, usando variables booleanas para comprobar la asignación de eventos a los elementos.

Comment: El gráfico base SVG se puede crear con cualquier programa vectorial como InkScape (gratuito) y después animarlo desde javaScript con Snap. No sólo animarlo, sino crear cualquier forma, o cambiar propiedades de las formas ya creadas. Mi animación consta de 600 líneas de código javaScript, no es una animación complicada y requiere mucho trabajo desarrollarla, pero es lo que tiene utilizar software libre. Otra posible alternativa mejor y de pago, podría ser Adobe Edge Animate. Pero no es mi objetivo usar software de pago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var clic = false;
function testClic(){
  if(clic){console.info("Evento asignado");}
  else {console.info("Evento no asignado");}
}
elemento.click(laFuncionClic);
clic = true;
testClic(); //Evento asignado
```

Comment: Esta sería la solución alternativa que yo necesito, sin embargo no es una solución que permita listar y comprobar todos los eventos asignados o no a un elemento SVG. Snap no contempla esta opción, así que habría que utilizar jQuery.

Comment: Tengo que añadir, que en la animación, los eventos se asignan o eliminan dinámicamente, según las acciones del usario. Pero en la respuesta está de forma estática para no extenderla demasiado.